# Has anyone been able to install Retrospectiva on a Windows machine?

Tags: retrospectiva

I've been looking into some bug trackers and Retrospectiva seems like a good tool. However, I am having all sorts of trouble installing it on my machine. I followed the guide on their site (http://retrospectiva.org/tickets/357) but it hasn't helped much and there don't seem to be a lot of users on their site that work with Windows.

I am wondering if any of the SO users have any experience working with Retrospectiva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully install Retrospectiva using [Robert Heim's guide](http://blog.robert-heim.de/karriere/programmierung/xampp-retrospectiva-on-windows-7/).

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for the link. I will try this and let you know how it works.